# OSX Filer and Python os.rename() to NAS ignore case only changes

Tags: python, macos, rename, nas

On my MacBook OSX Filer and Python os.rename ignore name changes that only involve case changes when working with files on a NAS. For python I've written a function for renaming files and folders to an intermediate name then renaming to the desired name when the change only involves case. Is there a better approach for making both OSX Filer and Python not ignore case only changes?

Comment: It's because of HFS+, which is a case insensitive but case preserving filesystem.  Is changing the underlying filesystem an option for you?

Comment: It is not Python -- it is the underlying file system which is case insensitive on OS X by default.

Comment: I corrected my question because I forgot the important detail that this rename problem only occurs when renaming files on a NAS which is formatted for Windows. Renaming files with only changes in case on the local Mac drive works fine.

Comment: I thought this site sent emails when my question received comments so I missed your comments. If there is not better ,fix than reformating the NAS I will stick with renaming to a temporary name. I seem to recall the ASUS router only works with a Windows formatted drive.